# How to prevent my marshmallows from melting in my hot cocoa?

Tags: temperature, beverages

Whenever I make a hot cocoa, adding powdered cocoa in a hot water *(not boiling)*, and add my marshmallows in it, the marshmallows just melts until they are completely gone. I really want to feel the mushy marshmallows melt in my mouth, not in my cocoa.

How can I prevent my marshmallows from melting in my cocoa?

Comment: OT: try using boiling milk instead of water. That is the only way to get a proper thick hot chocolate (maybe add a teaspoon of cornstarch to the mix). A tad longer but absolutely worth the wait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marshmallows will dissolve ("melt") in your hot cocoa for the same reason that they "melt" in your mouth: both provide heat and moisture. If you could somehow treat the marshmallows so that they didn't dissolve in the cocoa you wouldn't get the desired effect in your mouth either. **It comes down to a matter of timing: how can you keep the marshmallows intact until you drink the cocoa?**

I can think of three options:

1. Drink the cocoa more quickly.
2. Use larger marshmallows.
3. Add more marshmallows as necessary.

It's not clear from your question exactly what kind of marshmallows you're referring to. I suspect that you're talking about the crunchily dehydrated "micro-mini" marshmallows that come in a packet of hot cocoa mix. Call me a snob, but those things hardly qualify as a "marshmallow" at all; you should perhaps be happy that they dissolve, or else sift them out of the mix and throw them away! If you like them, though, you'll be happy to know that you can buy more: Amazon carries 12 oz. bags of dehydrated micro-mini marshmallows, and adding a spoonful to your cup when you're ready to drink should solve the problem.

If you feel like an upgrading your brew, pick up a bag of mini marshmallows and add a handful of those. Minis should be large enough to last for quite a while, and since they're not dehydrated they'll be somewhat sturdier in the cup. Marshmallows come in a number of sizes... if the minis don't last long enough for you, go with a few standard sized (approximately 1 inch) marshmallows. I've seen jumbo marshmallows in the store lately, but you'll probably need a larger cup if you want to have any room left for the cocoa. Try one of [these lovelies](http://www.candywarehouse.com/colors/pink-candy/products/pink-and-white-jumbo-marshmallow-twists-1kg-bag/).

Answer (score 5):

Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but when I was a kid, I'd just keep the marshmallows separate, and toss them in a couple at a time. (This might work best if you're also using a spoon.)

Comment: This is the only solution here that will actually work.

Answer (score -2):

Boil the chocolate powder. No, microwave it, because boiling would cause the bottom to burn. Microwave the chocolate powder in water and then stir it to get a thick paste. After cooling, keep it refrigerated.

Whenever you feel like having a cuppa, scoop a few spoons into your cup and mix in warm water. Throw in your marshmallows. You could even mix the chocolate into your cuppa-cino, and then the marshmallows = marsh-mellowed mocha-cino.

Comment: Non native English speaker here: What is a cuppa?

Comment: I'm confused why this would be different - either it's just as hot and they melt, or it's not hot enough, yes?

Comment: @nico "a cuppa" is British slang for "a cup of [coffee/tea/cocoa]"

Comment: None of this will work; they will melt.

Comment: They will not melt in warm water. Cocoa powder requires hot boiling or microwaving to form a paste. Once in paste form, only warm water is required to stir it into a perfect suspension. By the time you have completed stirring, a minute later, the cuppa would be so chilled that there would be no way of melting the marshmallows. That is how I do it.